# Read Windows boot options

Tags: windows, boot

I dug through the previous threads related to this question, but couldn't find any specific answer.

In newer versions of Windows (Win 10 in this example) you can press F10 when you're at the Windows Boot Manager in order to customize the boot options.

This works great, but is there a way to read these options (including "custom" variables, like in the screenshot) after Windows has booted? Is this logged somewhere?

On most Linux systems you're able to see the kernel arguments in /proc/cmdline - does Windows store its boot options in a similar fashion? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the boot options stored in the registry. I had previously looked through the registry without any luck, but I must have overlooked it.

For anyone interested, the boot options can be found within the key HKEY_LM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control. There's a string here named "SystemStartOptions" which contain the options passed at boot time.

[image]